# Is it possible to use uvesafb with nvidia proproetary drivers?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, tty

I would like to have high-resolution console with NVidia proprietary driver.
To accomplish that I'm trying to use *uvesafb*. So what I've done:

```
yaourt -S v86d
```

/etc/modprobe.d/uvesafb.conf:

```
mode_option=1920x1200-32 scroll=ywrap
```

It is the native resolution

I don't have vga parameters in my gummiboot configuration nor in modprobe.d (folowed archwiki page)

So I've made mkinitcpio,conf look like that

```
FILES="/etc/modprobe.d/uvesafb.conf"
HOOKS="base colors udev v86d autodetect modconf block resume filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

So I've got (after running mkinitcpio and rebooting) this:

```
pasha@primum ~ % journalctl -b --no-pager | grep uvesafb
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: NVIDIA Corporation, BIOS-P/N@N8857, Chip Rev   , OEM: NVIDIA, VBE v3.0
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: VBIOS/hardware doesn't support DDC transfers
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: no monitor limits have been set, default refresh rate will be used
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: scrolling: redraw
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: cannot reserve video memory at 0xf1000000
ноя 10 02:46:33 primum kernel: uvesafb: probe of uvesafb.0 failed with error -5
```

**Question**:

It is possible to fix my configuration and make it work with my card (NVidia GTX 570 and *nvidia* kernel driver)

**or**

at least to enlarge the resolution to, say, 1600x1200? Now I have 800x600.

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do with UEFI rather a problem with your video card.

This [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1225592#p1225592) on the Arch Linux BBs expand the issue a bit. Maybe an alternative, could use something like Plymouth, that it's suppose to work with the EFI Framebuffer.